# Does shared hosting hold some benefits over a VPS?

Tags: windows, hosting, asp.net

I was looking a for a windows host for my ASP.NET MVC app and the prices in softsyshosting looked very decent. However i fail to understand, why do they offer codename "Enterprise" Shared hosting at the same price point as the codename "Economy" VPS ?

Enterprise Shared:     http://www.softsyshosting.com/windows.aspx

The First Economy VPS: http://www.softsyshosting.com/windows-vps.aspx

Why would someone be willing to pay the same amount of money for 350GB less bandwith, less database storage, less disk space, no RDP control .. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, the main benefit of shared hosting is that you are not responsible for operating system maintenance, library/application server patches, security, etc.

Conversely, VPS hosting offers more flexibility in configuration, and depending on the provider, offers higher performance. (though this may not always be true)